# Graphics Ticks function evaluation on Wolfram Cloud

Tags: graphics, wolfram-cloud, ticks

I have been trying to get something like [`ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation/) to work in the cloud - however, it looks like the tick and grid functions are evaluated in some strange place, and not the main kernel: Consider e.g.

```
Graphics[{},Frame->True,FrameTicks->((range={##};{})&)]
```

When displaying this plot on the desktop, the `range` variable contains the plot range, as expected. In the cloud however, the variable is not set.
Does anyone know exactly is going on, and, more importantly, is there a workaround that allows you to get data from the ticks function back into the main kernel?

## Update

Some more investigation shows that the ticks function seems to be evaluated in a different process:

```
{$ProcessID,$KernelID}
Graphics[{},Frame->True,FrameTicks->(({{0,{$ProcessID,$KernelID}}})&)]
```

[image]